# How to add the privacy policy in designated field to Chrome Extension?

Tags: chrome-web-store

Is there any key or property or other way to add Additional Information in designated field to Chrome Extension.

**Note :** We are trying to add  Additional Information field in Chrome Extension Download UI as developer Privacy link but unable to add field , can you please  help us that how to add  the privacy policy in designated field.

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Confusingly this is associated with your publisher/developer account and not with the individual extension package.

For the most recent web store developer dashboard this worked for me:

1. Go to the web store developer dashboard at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole
2. Click Account on the left hand side
3. Fill in the *Privacy policy* field
4. Click Save (top right)

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is so counter intuitive. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 22):

You can add your privacy policy link here

[image]

Comment: This answer is too old. Should be deprecated in favor of the one from [Paul Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534175/1826211)

Answer (score 2):

finally i got answer , that we have to login with chrome web store where we have published the chrome Extension on that page scroll down at the button you will get Developer account info there we can add link as privacy link and support email address.