# App rejected due to privacy policy url issue but there no field for privacy policy in Store Listing

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

I have recently submitted an app which got rejected due to below error

```
> Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements
Apps that contain elements that appeal to children must comply with all Families Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:
> 
> Eligibility Issue Privacy policy You must provide a link to your app's
> privacy policy on your app's store listing page. This link must be
> maintained at all times while the app is available on Google Play, and
> it must link to a privacy policy that, among other things, accurately
> describes your app’s data collection and use. Please provide a link to
> a valid privacy policy in your app's store listing page in the Play
> Console. For more details, please refer to the Privacy policy section
> (#6) of the Families Policy Requirements.
```

But there is no privacy policy field in my Store listing page. I can't understand then why is my app getting rejected. Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add the privacy policy in designated field to Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577349/how-to-add-the-privacy-policy-in-designated-field-to-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google changed this to app content. Now you need to give privacy policy url in app content section. Please refer below image.

[image]

Comment: that is the problem there is no field there